# The maxima and minima of a family of curves

Tags: calculus

The family of curves is called to $f_{b}$ and $f_{b}(x)=e^{x-b}-x+2$.

i, determine the maxima and minima of $f_{b}$

ii, for which value of $b$  is the maxima and minima located on the $X$ axis?

iii,the tangent to the graph of $f_{b}$ at the intersection with the Y-axis is parallel to $y=x$. For which value of $b$ ist that?

I assume that I have to take the first derivative of $f_{b}$, so $f'_{b}=e^{x-b}-1$ and it gives, that I have to solve the equation $f'_{b}=e^{x-b}-1=0$ which gives that $x=b$ is that way which leads to the solution? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f_b(x)$ is $f'_b(x)=e^{x-b}-1$. If we want to find extreme points we need to find solutions to $f'_b(x)=0$. In our case we get 1 solution namely $x=b$. Note that this point is $(b,f_b(x))=(b,3-b)$. If we want it to land on the X axis we need $3-b=0$ so $b=3$. Finally we want to look at our intersection with the Y axis so we subtitute $x=0$ to the original the slope function $f_b'(x)$ and get $e^{-b}-1$. We want this to be parallel to $y=x$ and therefore have slope of $1$. So $e^{-b}-1=1$ and so $-\ln (2)=b$.